# Send Notification when document get published in Library

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-library, online, ms-flow

I want to send approval email when document get published in Library SP online. Is there any way to trigger MS flow on item /document published??   Or any other ways to implement this requirement.?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

In your situation, you enabled minor/major versions as well as Content Approval in your library and you need an approval flow when a document has been published for a new major verison, right?

If so, this would be the correct workaround for a Trigger-Condition to start only on Publishing Major Versions:

```
@contains(triggerBody()?['{VersionNumber}'],'.0')
```

It would be better to use the Lists/Libraries Content Approval Feature with the Pending Status:

```
@equals(triggerBody()['{ModerationStatus}'],'Pending')
```

[image]

Then, You can refer to the below articles to complete the following actions in the approval flow:

[Trigger approvals from a SharePoint document library](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/trigger-sharepoint-library)

[Trigger approvals from SharePoint lists](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/power-automate/trigger-sharepoint-list)